# com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am Making an app For Accessing users real-time location and displaying the latitude, longitude and altitude to the user, the app did run successfully on the android emulator but is showing error when I installed it in my phone (ie real-time device), as it's showing an error of buffer overflow and i don't know how to get rid of this error please help me solve this problem.

MainActivity.java code:-

```
package com.example.hikersapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
TextView latitude;
TextView longitude;
TextView altitude;
TextView accuracy;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, 
@NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    { 

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates
(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

    }

}

/*public void entered(View view)
{



}

 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    latitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    longitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.longitude);
    altitude=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.altitude);
    accuracy=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.accuracy);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            longitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            accuracy.setText(String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));


            Log.i("locaiton",location.toString());


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] 
   {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        Log.i("entered","1");
    }
    else
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {



locationManager.requestLocationUpdates
(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
            Log.i("entered","2");

            }
        }




    }
 }
```

main.xml code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="552dp"
    android:layout_height="1033dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/background1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="386dp"
    android:layout_height="417dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.953"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/altitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/accuracy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/enter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="184dp"
    android:text="SHOW"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

please Help me solve this error.